# AlertDialog inside spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to create warning message when spinner item is changed but in case user click's No 
selection should be canceled and selected item should stay as it was previously. If I store last selected spinner item and pass it to spinner when user chooses No
it will tirger onItemSelectedListener which i don't want to.

I tried to use OnTouchListener but this doesn't help because spinner list is displayed imidiately after spinner is touched.

See my code below for better understanding.

```
    spinnerSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, final int position, long id) {

            if (!ShoppingCart.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchProductActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Selecting new finacier will empty your basket.").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        //do some work
                        //storing lastSelectedFinancier
                    }

                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        //cancel selection
                        //spinnerSearch.setSelection(lastSelectedFinancier)

                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = dialog.show();

                TextView messageView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            } else {
                //do some other work
                //lastSelectedFinancier
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        //lastSelectedFinancier

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found workaround for this problem. Instead of spinner I used textbox (whit spinner style) and combine it with alert dialog for creating list.
Maybe it is not best solution but it worked for me :)))

public class SpinnerItem {

```
String spinnerText;
String value;

public SpinnerItem(String text, String value) {
    this.spinnerText = text;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getSpinnerText() {
    return spinnerText;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String toString() {
    return spinnerText;
}
```

`public class SearchProductActivity extends BaseActivity {`

```
private EditText txtSearch;
private ListView listProducts;
private Button btnShoppingCart;
private EditText txtSelectFinancier;
private DevRestHelper rest;
private ListOfProducts adapter;
public static String financierRelationNumber;
private int numberOfItemsInBasket = 0;

private List<ProductModel> products = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_product);

    initControls();
    getProjectSupplier();
    financierRelationNumber = String.valueOf(OrderData.Financiers.get(0).RelationNumber);
    txtSelectFinancier.setText(String.valueOf(OrderData.Financiers.get(0).Name));
    GetProducts(financierRelationNumber);
    setButtonActions();
    ShoppingCart.ProductOwnerId = getProjectSupplier().get(0).getValue();
    ShoppingCart.ProductOwner = getProjectSupplier().get(0).getSpinnerText();

}

    private void initControls() {
    btnShoppingCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_product_btnShoppingCart);
    listProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_product_listProducts);
    txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_product_txtName);
    txtSelectFinancier = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_product_txtFinancier);

}

private void setButtonActions() {

    txtSelectFinancier.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!ShoppingCart.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchProductActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.err_selecting_new_finacier_will_empty_your_basket)).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listDialog(SearchProductActivity.this, "", getProjectSupplier(), txtSelectFinancier);
                        listProducts.setAdapter(null);
                        ShoppingCart.emptyCartItems();
                        ShoppingCart.ProductOwner = txtSelectFinancier.getText().toString();

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = dialog.show();

                TextView messageView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            } else
                listDialog(SearchProductActivity.this, "", getProjectSupplier(), txtSelectFinancier);
        }
    });

}

    private List<SpinnerItem> getProjectSupplier() {

    List<SpinnerItem> items = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();

    for (DetermineFinanciersModel finaciers : OrderData.Financiers) {
        items.add(new SpinnerItem(finaciers.Name, String.valueOf(finaciers.RelationNumber)));
    }

    return items;

}

private void listDialog(Context context, String title, final List<SpinnerItem> list, final TextView control) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (SpinnerItem spinnerItem : list) {
        strings.add(spinnerItem.getSpinnerText());
    }

    final CharSequence[] items = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);

    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItem) {
            control.setText(list.get(selectedItem).getSpinnerText());
            ShoppingCart.ProductOwnerId = list.get(selectedItem).getValue();
            GetProducts(list.get(selectedItem).getValue());
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with checkboxes: I set an onCheckedChangeListener to listen to user input, then I update the checkbox from settings, or alert dialog, like you are doing, which, again triggers onCheckedChangeListener :) This is how I worked around it:

1) Instead of "spinnerSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {...", create new OnItemSelectedListener object with a global declaration. I'm going to call it myClickListener

2) Inside this object's body, when you create the alert dialog, inside the "No" button declaration, change your code a little bit to set the listener to null, then to change the spinner value, and then to set the listener to myClickListener again.

Try modifying your code like this, and let me know if it works:

```
    private OnItemClickListener myClickListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, final int position, long id) {

            if (!ShoppingCart.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchProductActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Selecting new finacier will empty your basket.").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        //do some work
                        //storing lastSelectedFinancier
                    }

                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Modified code:
                        spinnerSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(null) //Disable the onItemClickListener
                        spinnerSearch.setSelection(lastSelectedFinancier) //Cancel selection, while the OnClickListener is disabled
                        spinnerSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(myClickListener) //Enable onItemClickListener
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = dialog.show();

                TextView messageView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            } else {
                //do some other work
                //lastSelectedFinancier
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        //lastSelectedFinancier

    }); //End of myClickListener declaration


    //This goes into your code:
    spinnerSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(myClickListener)
```

Comment: I did exact same thing and I get following error: cannot convert from new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} to AdapterView.OnItemClickListener